# Updating dictionaries to append file data

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to make a function that updates two dictionaries with data from a open file. The first dict one would be a "person to countries" dict and the second one would be a "person to people" dict.

For example, the "person to countries" would be something like `{'Greg Van' : ['Canada', 'America'], 'Tori Mars' : ['Thailand']}` and the "person to people" dict would be be `{'Greg Van' : ['Mike Wu', 'Emily Salt'], 'Mia Tan' : ['Sandy Bay', 'Dan Hamilton']}`.

The parameters of the function would be
(file, dict of {string : list of strings}, dict of {string : list of strings}) -> NoneType

The text file would be something like:

```
Chan, Ferah
Canada
Pritchett, Mitchell
Pritchett, Jay

Rad, Sarah
France
America
MacKenzie, Corey

Delgado, Manny
Luong, Sam

Vu, Linda
China
Khan, Jane
```

where the first line of each list is a person and then it would list 0 or more countries that they have lived in, along with 0 or more people. There would also be a blank line space between each person. Each list/paragraph here in the file is related to each other.

I don't know how to update the two existing dicts("person to countries" and "person to people") with the data from the given file (which includes a person, countries, and/or people). So basically I want to append the data to the two dicts.

All I know is that I can differentiate the countries and the people by the comma since countries don't have them.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?  Updating a dictionary with information read from a file is no different than updating a dictionary any other way.  Do you know how to open and read a file in Python?

Comment: Though we can see clearly how to differentiate between Country an Person (checking for existence of comma), we still have no information on how to identify the links between the person and the country.  Are countries meant to be associated with all people within the same line-separated 'paragraphs?'

Comment: Yes, the person and the country/countries are supposed to be associated with each other, so within the same paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the pattern I see, I can tell that the difference between the countries and the animals is that Countries are Capitalized, so, you could do a variety of things: you can have a dict where each letter is the key and a tuple that is the value, inside the value (the tuple) you would have two lists, one for countries and the other for pets. The other approach is to have one dict instead of the tuple and the dict would have two elements, I'll show you the structure of this dict:

```
    people = {'A': {'countries':['Canada',], 'pets':['dog', 'cat']}}
```

That would be the mapping in the dict of the first element. The code would be something like:

```
    people = {}
    file_read = open("asdf.in", "r")

    current_person = file_read.readline().strip()

    while current_person:    
        people[current_person] = {}
        line = file_read.readline().strip()
        people[current_person]['countries'] = []
        people[current_person]['pets'] = []
        while line:
            if line.istitle(): people[current_person]['countries'].append(line)
            elif line.islower(): people[current_person]['pets'].append(line)
            line = file_read.readline().strip()

        current_person = file_read.readline().strip()

    print people
```

Comment: I changed pets to people for the dictionary key. Sorry for the confusion.
Also, if the output is NoneType, I would have to remove the print statement, right?

Comment: Right, the print is only used to test what was posted before. Now you can use the same data structure the only thing you have to change is the algorithm to process the values

Comment: But I don't get what I should do if I don't want to make one dict, but instead update the existing two dicts ("person to countries" and "person to people") with the data from given file (person's name, countries, and people).. so more like appending/updating the data to the two dicts

Comment: Also, is there another method to replace "istitle" and "islower"? I haven't learned these yet.. Sorry for asking so many questions

Comment: well, you could implement istitle and islower by yourself, the only thing they do is to check whether a str has all its words capitalized or if all the string is lower case. To update both dicts you should change the processing, but again, my solution only works for the previous composition of the data.